# What capabilities does the Kazakhstan root CA have which other "trusted" CA's don't?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-revocation

Kazakhstan recently tried to force users again to install a root CA. This has been rejected again by numerous western tech companies.

https://www.engadget.com/tech-giants-browsers-block-kazakhstan-web-surveillance-080031499.html

How they do it might be questionable. But consider they would have gone the official way to put up a root CA and get it into OS or browser root CA stores. Or instead the US would force users to install a root CA. Lots of countries already own a CA. Would this be any different regarding capabilities to snoop and modify traffic?

Comment: "Lots of countries already own a CA." [citation needed]

Comment: They might be forcing OEMs to install their root CA and asking users to press on "add permanent exception" on webpage to avoid seeing the warning.

Comment: @defalt: *"... asking users to press on "add permanent exception" on webpage  ..."* - this would need to be asked for each domain visited and not for each certificate used, i.e. it does not scale. Moreover it will not work when the site uses HSTS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would this be any different regarding capabilities to snoop and modify traffic?

In case of Kazakhstan the government essentially urged their citizen to explicitly install this CA as trust into the browsers. This is similar to how SSL interception in companies is done.

CA installed this explicit way are handled slightly differently from pre-installed CA: **any pinning of a domain to a specific certificate or CA is actually ignored** with many browsers in this case. This means it would be possible to intercept SSL traffic to google.com, facebook.com even though browsers like Chrome have these [domain pinned to specific CA](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/2b1530f0c38ddff99365a8a04974bbd1aee2572f/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json). Such interception would not be possible though if the CA just comes as pre-installed since it this case pinning is enforced.

Note that this is not a difference in the CA certificate itself, but only if it was explicitly added as trusted or if it came pre-installed with the browser/OS.

Comment: Fascinating, I had no idea Chrome pinned certain CAs for a small set of sites (shows how broken the CA system is).  It's also interesting to see who is in that list: google, twitter, facebook all are obvious, dropbox not that surprising, but tor and spideroak got themselves included too.  I wonder if the security folks at my company are going to start adding "have the domain in the browser CA pinned list" into their auditing checklists.

Comment: There's also [the DNS CAA record](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/caa-record/) where a site administrator can specify in their DNS record which CAs are allowed to issue certs for their domain. I'm not sure how widely supported it is for browsers to check CAA records when validating certs.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth: CAA is not intended for browser but for the CA's. They are relevant for the time of certificate issuance not for the time of certificate validation.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Oops! Yes of course! So CAA is not relevant to this thread since a CA built for the purpose of spying would not need to honour the CAA record.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov That's indeed an interesting question why they keep it for some domains while HPKP has been deprecated since quite a while and you can't even pin stuff yourself and would need to recompile chrome. Also Windows Updates are pinned  as far as I know.

Comment: @Preetham: Pinning using a HTTP header (i.e. HPKP) was deprecated because it caused too much trouble (like permanent inaccessibility of a domain) if domain owners failed with a proper setup. Pinning a few selected domains in source code is different from this and these domains are also unlikely to accidentally screw up their setup.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The replacement aka CT does not really look usable up to now and has issues itself. But then ... what hasn't . I still do not really see a reason why an end user should not be able to add pins himself. If the remote end cert then changes you'd see a warning at least.

Comment: @Preetham: For a detailed discussion on the topic of HPKP removal see [this Firefox issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1412438) which also refers to [The death knell for HPKP?](https://scotthelme.co.uk/the-death-knell-for-hpkp/).

Answer (score 3):

Each web browser, operating system, and even things like the java jvm maintain their own root CA trust store, and each will have their own policies for which CAs they will include. Since it's impossible to give an answer in general, I will answer specifically about Mozilla / Firefox.

## Mozilla Root Store Policy

Mozilla's policies for all the things a CA needs to do before it will be accepted into the Mozilla Root Store can be read here:

- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/security-group/certs/policy/

It includes:

- **Section 1: Introduction**
- **Section 2:** operational requirements that the CA needs to follow.

  - **Section 2.1: CA Operations**; mainly minimum network security practices the CA needs to follow with their own internal networks
  - **Section 2.2: Validation Practices**: what level of validation the CA needs to do that the end user is who they say they are before issuing a cert (or owns the domain they are requesting a cert for).
  - **Section 2.3: Baseline Requirements Conformance**: in addition to complying with Mozilla policies, a CA also needs to comply with all the [Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/) as set out by the CA/Browser Forum; a working group of all the browser and CA companies.
  - **Section 2.4: Incidents**: the process for reporting and correcting an incident where the CA broke one of the requirements.
- **Section 3: Audits**: procedures for public auditors to come to the CA's datacentre and verify that they are following the rules.
- **Sections 4 - 8**: technical details that are not relevant to this question.

---

## Kazakhstan's root CA, aka "Would this be different for other countries?"

> How they do it might be questionable. But consider they would have gone the official way to put up a root CA and get it into OS or browser root CA stores.

But how they do it is the whole point here. If the Kazakhstan government wanted to run a public CA; follow the Mozilla and CA/Browser Forum rules, only issue certs to the legitimate domain administrators / owners of a site, then sure, I'm sure Mozilla would let them into their Root Program after they have passed their audits like any other CA.

From your question, it sounds like the Kazakhstan government does not want to comply with Mozilla's rules. They don't want to run a publicly-trusted root that gives end user privacy and security; they want to run a spy agency that does exactly the opposite.

---

> Or instead the US would force users to install a root CA. Lots of countries already own a CA. Would this be any different regarding capabilities to snoop and modify traffic?

I don't think so. There are of course examples of the US government requiring companies to share their databases, but the CA industry is very transparent and public and well-audited. I think it would be difficult for any nation state, even the US government, to get a publicly-trusted CA to issue them "snooping" certificates without the international community noticing.

Comment: I currently can't find the exact bugzilla but apparently 5 years ago they tried to go the official way. This did not went far and maybe was just a low level effort to look legit. I'm pretty sure their intentions are not securing their users. While the capabilities are a bit different when compared to currently trusted certs as pointed out by @SteffenUllrich this will make dragnet surveillance a bit harder. But attacking individual users should not be that hard without someone noticing unless users are really looking out for it (few if any do) Same applies for any other trusted CA.

Comment: I also did not look at the auditing procedures yet. Do they control at random unknown intervals? When they come today, they probably won't come the next one ...

Comment: @Preetham I don't think it's random audits. I think they are scheduled annual. Usually you are expecting the CA to be honest, but maybe cutting corners here and there, you don't expect the CA to be outright malicious (like owned by a spy agency).

Answer (score 0):

Valid CA are authorized by the browser vendors or operating system vendors. Not by law.

A nation having a CA would make it possible to spy on HTTPS, and all vendors would refuse that. In fact, France was once caught in the act of misusing a CA of one its national institutions and this CA got revoked *fast*.

Comment: There are several government agencies listed here: https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/mozilla/CAInformationReport  Obviously vendors did not refuse in these cases.

Comment: @Preetham I guess I do not have the same definition of "government agency" than the website you cited. And the French agency I wrote about was indeed allowed too, before it was caught abusing its trust. I think you misinterpreted what I wrote.